# Length for naming variables

Tags: coding-style, naming-conventions

Im currently in the worst predicament since ive started as a trainee in programming a year ago.

I am currently in an internship for 2 months and ive been told that:

> "The longer and descriptive your variable and function names are the
>   better"

**The problem in my opinion is:**

Things can get really unreadable. I mean variable names should be obvious on sight without the eyes having to scan from left to right.

For example lets assume we have a class named car:

```
Car {

   int drivingSpeed = 1;

   int drivingSpeedOfCar: 2;

}
```

I find the second variable unneccesarily descriptive since the class the variable is contained in already describes what speed refers to.

Then there is this:

```
Moon {
   float rotationX = 45.0; 
   float rotationAngleX = 45.0;
   float currentRotationXAngleInDegrees = 45;
   float currentRotationXAngleInDegreesOfMoon = 45;
}
```

I find rotationX already explains it all. It refers to the moons rotation angle. We know its and angle when we do some sort of rotation. Then AngleInDegrees part seems kind of overkill and makes the name more complicated but it is descriptive.

**My question is:** Which of the examples is the most accepted? Very long descriptive names so that anyone can understand whats going on or reducing the variable names, thus also reducing the overall verbosity?

Answer (score 1):

First all, the length of that Variable names is not causing any problems to the running of the program rather on debugging part, especially when another programmer want to help you out. i will suggest that you use the most meaningful names for your variables and do not confuse them with methods or classes.

Answer (score 1):

From the Source : Coding Techniques and Programming Practices  https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa260844(v=vs.60).aspx

Names

Perhaps one of the most influential aids to understanding the logical flow of an application is how the various elements of the application are named. A name should tell "what" rather than "how." By avoiding names that expose the underlying implementation, which can change, you preserve a layer of abstraction that simplifies the complexity. For example, you could use GetNextStudent() instead of GetNextArrayElement().

A tenet of naming is that difficulty in selecting a proper name may indicate that you need to further analyze or define the purpose of an item. Make names long enough to be meaningful but short enough to avoid being wordy. Programmatically, a unique name serves only to differentiate one item from another. Expressive names function as an aid to the human reader; therefore, it makes sense to provide a name that the human reader can comprehend. However, be certain that the names chosen are in compliance with the applicable language's rules and standards.

Following are recommended naming techniques:
Routines

```
Avoid elusive names that are open to subjective interpretation, such as Analyze() for a routine, or xxK8 for a variable. Such names contribute to ambiguity more than abstraction.
In object-oriented languages, it is redundant to include class names in the name of class properties, such as Book.BookTitle. Instead, use Book.Title.
Use the verb-noun method for naming routines that perform some operation on a given object, such as CalculateInvoiceTotal().
In languages that permit function overloading, all overloads should perform a similar function. For those languages that do not permit function overloading, establish a naming standard that relates similar functions.
```